# creating registration and login form in node.js and mongodb

Tags: mongodb, node.js, express

I am new to node.js and want to create a registration and login page for user.also there has to proper authorisation for the user.I want to store the user information inside mongodb database.How can i achieve this.can someone provide me the code to do so, so that i can get started with node.js and mongodb.Please help

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You can find a complete sample of what you're trying to do in the [Nodepad application by Alex Young](https://github.com/alexyoung/nodepad). The 2 important file you should take a look at are these 2:
https://github.com/alexyoung/nodepad/blob/master/models.js 
https://github.com/alexyoung/nodepad/blob/master/app.js

A part of the model look like this:

```
  User = new Schema({
    'email': { type: String, validate: [validatePresenceOf, 'an email is required'], index: { unique: true } },
    'hashed_password': String,
    'salt': String
  });

  User.virtual('id')
    .get(function() {
      return this._id.toHexString();
    });

  User.virtual('password')
    .set(function(password) {
      this._password = password;
      this.salt = this.makeSalt();
      this.hashed_password = this.encryptPassword(password);
    })
    .get(function() { return this._password; });

  User.method('authenticate', function(plainText) {
    return this.encryptPassword(plainText) === this.hashed_password;
  });

  User.method('makeSalt', function() {
    return Math.round((new Date().valueOf() * Math.random())) + '';
  });

  User.method('encryptPassword', function(password) {
    return crypto.createHmac('sha1', this.salt).update(password).digest('hex');
  });

  User.pre('save', function(next) {
    if (!validatePresenceOf(this.password)) {
      next(new Error('Invalid password'));
    } else {
      next();
    }
  });
```

I think he also [explains the code on the dailyjs site](http://dailyjs.com/tags.html#lmawa).

Comment: Alex's tutorial was exactly what I needed.

Comment: http://dailyjs.com/2010/12/06/node-tutorial-5/ Here is the page for authentication.

Answer (score 21):

I wrote a [boilerplate project](https://github.com/braitsch/node-login) to do [exactly this.](http://node-login.braitsch.io/) It supports account creation, password retrieval via email, sessions, local cookies for remembering users when they return and secure password encryption via bcyrpt.

[There's also a detailed explanation of the project's architecture on my blog.](http://www.quietless.com/kitchen/building-a-login-system-in-node-js-and-mongodb/)

Comment: the demo is good.. but the code is written in a not very friendly way :/

Comment: I disagree. Unless he has changed it since June 13 2012.  I think the code is well structured and I can immediately tell what is going on.  Worth checking out.

Comment: This was a great boilerplate for me. I definitely modified it (as you should), to fit my needs. I am debating on integrating this approach with passport. I will also switch to Mongoose for handling MongoDB, just haven't gotten there yet. In any case, this is a good reference project.

Answer (score 10):

For an easy way to get started take a look at [ExpressJS](http://expressjs.com/) + [MongooseJS](http://mongoosejs.com/) + [MongooseAuth](https://github.com/bnoguchi/mongoose-auth).

In particular, that last plug-in provides a standard simple way to do logins using several different authentication methods (Password, Facebook, Twitter, etc.)

Comment: is there a way were i can store login details inside database(mongodb)and later on retrieve the details and check whether the particular user exists in the database, if yes then the user will be allowed to login and redirected to another page.else he would not be.can anyone provide me the code for reference

Comment: @DarHamid Mongoose-auth automatically stores the user info (fetched from password after registration, facebook, twitter, etc) into a mongodb. Clone it and run the example. See the Readme.md for more info.

Comment: Worth noting 2 years later that Sadly MongooseAuth isn't well maintained and to use PassportJS instead..