# How to do authentication with Node.js, Express and Mongoose?

Tags: authentication, node.js, express, mongoose

I've made simple nodejs application by using nodejs+express. Now I want to make user authentification. I want to realize session handling by using mongoose. 
Can you advise some example?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Some useful links:

[how to implement login auth in node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7990890/how-to-implement-login-auth-in-node-js/8003291#8003291)

[creating registration and login form in node.js and mongodb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8051631/creating-registration-and-login-form-in-node-js-and-mongodb/8111646#8111646)

Also session management isn't done by Mongoose, but by connect-mongodb or connect-redis. You can checkout an example on how to do user auth and session management in a real application here:

https://github.com/alexyoung/nodepad/blob/master/app.js

Further explanations for that app you can find here: http://dailyjs.com/tag/lmawa or http://dailyjs.com/2010/12/06/node-tutorial-5/

Answer (score 14):

Just use mongoose-auth by Brian Noguchi https://github.com/bnoguchi/mongoose-auth

It's a drop in solution for your question, it's well documented and extensible.

**EDIT**

`mongoose-auth` is no longer maintained. If you need to make it work with more recent versions of mongoose (ie > v3.x.x) and express (ie. > v3.x.x), here's an excerpt from a `package.json` file I'm currently using in production (It's hacky but it works):

```
"everyauth": "https://github.com/bnoguchi/everyauth/tarball/express3",
"mongoose-3x-types": "~1.0.5",
"mongoose-auth": "https://github.com/cbou/mongoose-auth/tarball/everymodule-fix",
```

I **you are starting a new project** don't use `mongoose-auth`, instead try out [passport](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport). It offers the same functionality, it's very flexible, however it has a different api. It's part of the [locomotive](http://locomotivejs.org/) MVC framework and as such it's actively maintained.

Comment: Just dropping combing SO and saw this. Mongoose-auth is awesome, but it hasn't been updated in forever and as it sits it has a lot of deprecated code.

Comment: very true, it seems the project is no longer maintained. AFAIK, The de-facto lib to use now is [passport](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport)

Comment: Can't get passport to work with express v3... Is it even compatible :O :(

Answer (score 5):

I've posted a complete example of a complete auth system using mongoose + expressjs on here, in case you want to take a look:

[Simple login page in nodejs using express and passport with mongodb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19024878/simple-login-page-in-nodejs-using-express-and-passport-with-mongodb/19025505#19025505)