# using node and sockets with redis to push data from c# app to web interface

Tags: node.js, express, redis, socket.io

i am attempting to develop my first node application.. That being said i have a C# app that submits user specific json data via POST to a url lets call it `//localhost/data/send`, this data will be sent every ~ 1-5 seconds(havent decided).

I then am going to have a website that requires the user to login, and then polls for that users data and shows it. Now rather than refreshing the page every x seconds i figured i could use some sort of socket or event based technology such as socket.io or redis pub/sub to push the data to the connected client.

But heres the catch, how do i go about ensuring two things:

1. The connected user ONLY has access to their information

   1. im currently using express, but thats open for anything really..
2. The data is only sent when there is a user logged into the remote web interface

My thought process was, that when the user logs in to the desktop c# app it begins polling to check if/when the user is logged into the web interface.

Once the user logs into the web interface, the desktop app recognizes the session id based on the username that matches between the desktop app and the web app. It then begins to push to that session id only.

Is redis even needed for this? Or can i get by with a simple mysql table, and socket.io?

The data does not need to be persistent once the user logs off.

Answer (score 1):

If the data does not need to be persisted and this is an internal simple app with few users, then I would create a module which has a queue and methods to add and remove items from the queue.

The module would have a queue per logged in user. When the user leaves the page (onunload) you log them out and remove the queue for that user. When your calling c# app calls to add an event, the queue will not exist which means the user is not logged in. When the user logs in, you create the queue for that user.

see here for how to do auth in express. [How to do authentication with Node.js, Express and Mongoose?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8397977/how-to-do-authentication-with-node-js-express-and-mongoose)

Something like this:

```
var queue = {};

exports.queueEvent = function(user, event){
  if(queue[user]){
    queue[userid].push(event);
  }
  else{
    return 'user not logged in, come back later';
  }
};

exports.getEvent = function(user){
  if(!queue[user]){
    queue[user] = [];  // this indicates the user is logged in.
    return null; // no events yet.
  }
  return queue[user.shift();
}

exports.logOutUser = function(user){
  if(queue[user]){
    delete queue[user];
  }
}
```