# Simple login page in nodejs using express and passport with mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, authentication, passport.js

I created a simple login form in using Jade and Express at /login
the form data is sent via POST to /login

At first It was just string based matching ( if username== && password== ) then redirect to /home or redirect to /login

Simple.

Now I want to make it database driver, username and password to be stored on a mongodb database, match username password from db and do the proceedings.

I wish to use passportJS for this, but I'm totally struck at it, from creating database to configuring passport.

Can someone just help me how to make a simple database driven login page ? I'm very new to nodejs stuff.
Any help would be seriously appreciated

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Here is a simple setup using passport to login / logout the users:

### On the main app.js file

```
/* Auth config  --------------------------------*/
// @see http://frederiknakstad.com/authentication-in-single-page-applications-with-angular-js/

var passport = require('passport');
var User = require('./app/models/User'),

passport.use(User.localStrategy);
passport.serializeUser(User.serializeUser);
passport.deserializeUser(User.deserializeUser);

// Default session handling. Won't explain it as there are a lot of resources out there
app.use(express.session({
    secret: "mylittlesecret",
    cookie: {maxAge: new Date(Date.now() + 3600000)}, // 1 hour
    maxAge: new Date(Date.now() + 3600000), // 1 hour
    store: new RedisStore(config.database.redis), // You can not use Redis 
}));

// The important part. Must go AFTER the express session is initialized
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

// Set up your express routes
var auth = require('./app/controllers/authController.js');

app.post('/auth/login', auth.login);
app.post('/auth/logout', auth.logout);
app.get('/auth/login/success', auth.loginSuccess);
app.get('/auth/login/failure', auth.loginFailure);
```

### On your user model (ej. app/models/User.js)

I'm using the passport-local module, which further simplifies the login logic:
https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-local

```
/* Your normal user model      ----------------------*/
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    ObjectId = mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    PassportLocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;

var schema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: {type:String, required:true, trim:true},
    email: {type:String, required: true, trim: true, lowercase:true, unique: true},
    image: {type:String},
    password: {type:String, required: true },
    created: {type: Date, default: Date.now}
});

/* Auth properties      ---------------------------*/
/* (passport)           ---------------------------*/

// This is your main login logic
schema.statics.localStrategy = new PassportLocalStrategy({
        usernameField: 'email',
        passwordField: 'password',
    },

    // @see https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-local
    function (username, password, done){
        var User = require('./User');
        User.findOne({email: username}, function(err, user){
            if (err) { return done(err); }

            if (!user){
                return done(null, false, { message: 'User not found.'} );
            }
            if (!user.validPassword(password)){
                return done(null, false, { message: 'Incorrect password.'} );
            }

            // I'm specifying the fields that I want to save into the user's session
            // *I don't want to save the password in the session
            return done(null, {
                id: user._id,
                name: user.name,
                image: user.image,
                email: user.email,
            });
        });
    }
);

schema.methods.validPassword = function(password){
    if (this.password == password){
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}

schema.statics.serializeUser = function(user, done){
    done(null, user);
};

schema.statics.deserializeUser = function(obj, done){
    done(null, obj);
};

var model = mongoose.model('User', schema);

exports = module.exports = model;
```

### On app/controllers/authController.js

I'm using a single-page application, so I'm returning JSON on login / logout. If you wish to redirect to somewhere else, you will have to modify the "login success" and "login failure" functions (or call res.render(...) or whatever).

```
var passport = require('passport');
var AuthController = {

    // Login a user 
    login: passport.authenticate('local', {
        successRedirect: '/auth/login/success',
        failureRedirect: '/auth/login/failure'
    }),

    // on Login Success callback
    loginSuccess: function(req, res){
        res.json({
            success: true,
            user: req.session.passport.user
        });
    },

    // on Login Failure callback
    loginFailure: function(req, res){
        res.json({
            success:false, 
            message: 'Invalid username or password.'
        });
    },

    // Log out a user   
    logout: function(req, res){
        req.logout();
        res.end();
    },

};

exports = module.exports = AuthController;
```

Lastly, you should point your login form (which needs to have the `method="post"` attribute set) to /auth/login. On login success, the "loginSuccess" callback will be executed. On login failure, the "loginFailure" callback will be executed.

### Edit:

You can create new users in your mongo database by executing something like:

```
// On your main app.js file
app.post('/auth/register', auth.register);

// On your authController.js file, as per the previous example
var User = require('./app/models/User'); // The model we defined in the previous example    

...
register: function(req, res){
    User.create({name: req.body.name, email: req.body.email, password: req.body.password}, function(err){
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        ... // Your register error logic here
        res.redirect('/* Your error redirection path */');
        return;
      }

      res.redirect('/* Your success redirection path */'); 
    });
},
...
```

Then, point a registration form to /auth/register. I didn't validated the data, but you should validate it before trying to save the user.

Comment: In otherwords its not simple :p

Comment: given that it would take you 15 seconds to create a working app, I don't understand why you've given a half-written answer that requires a lot of rigging (for a new node user). I'm new to node, as you may have guessed, and I am, therefore, trying to figure things out (quickly at that—as I have a hard deadline), and so it is very difficult for me to fill in the blanks, so to speak. A full example would be greatly appreciated.