# Make a login form using express in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to create a login page in node.js, I've created `app.js` with my `index.ejs` as follows

**My app.js:**

```
var email=req.body.email;
var password=req.body.password;
connection.query('INSERT INTO  userlogin(email, password) VALUES (? , ?);' , [email, password], 
                  function(err, docs) {
                       if (err) res.json(err);
                          res.redirect('users.ejs');
              });
```

**My indes.ejs:**

```
Email:<input type="text" /><br>
Password:  <input type="password"/><br>  
<input type="button" value="Submit"/>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19024878/simple-login-page-in-nodejs-using-express-and-passport-with-mongodb

Comment: My problem is that how we make a login form using node.js with express and used of mysql database.

Comment: Did you get any error ? See http://www.crashcoder.com/nodejs-user-autentication-and-session-storage-using-express-mysql-passport/

Comment: Thank you vinz243, to solve my problem.