# Stashing user data in PhoneGap Browser

Tags: javascript, node.js, cookies, web-applications, phonegap-build

I am making a local webapp that will have a login page.

I am using PhoneGap to make the app local and I wold like to stash some user data in a cookie or something like that.

So far I have been stashing the username and encrypted password in the cookie, is that very unsafe and what wold be a better and safer way to do this?

Comment: Have you considered using an alternative such as bearer tokens to skip the storage of sensitive user information in the first place?

Comment: No I have not considered that. Can I do it in node?

Comment: You can! I answered with what I hope are some good starting points for your consideration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To respond with better alternatives, I'd like to point you to [Stormpath's Auth article](https://stormpath.com/blog/choosing-nodejs-authentication-strategy) and a related [StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8397977/how-to-do-authentication-with-node-js-express-and-mongoose). The Stormpath article has some big name options if you don't like writing this sort of code (I love it.) and the related question has a great answer with examples I'd have stolen otherwise.

I'd love to quote you some snippets to clear things up, but there's a zillion ways to handle implementations. The basic flow is this:

1. Client passes credentials to Server
2. Server Authenticates credentials
3. Server generates a token (UUID, random string, whatever)
4. Server replies with the requested info and token
5. Client sends token with the next request
6. Server matches token to authenticated session
7. Repeat 4-6 until the session is expired (Logout or timeout)

My own implementations usually continue differently to prevent some other security issues:

7. Server deprecates the token used by the request
8. Server generates a new token
9. Server replies with requested info and new token
10. Repeat steps 5-9 until the session is expired (Logout or timeout)

Comment: Thank you very mutch! @gelliott181